# Error on retrieving column from ORACLE DB

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a strange mistake that some of the column cant be retrieved.

Here is my .PHP code,

```
$fabSql = "SELECT FABRICATION.* FROM FABRICATION";

    $fabParse = oci_parse($conn, $fabSql);
    oci_execute($fabParse);

        echo '<table>';
            echo '<thead>';
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>HEAD_MARK</td>';
                    echo '<td>PROJECT</td>';
                    echo '<td>MARKING DATE</td>';
                    echo '<td>MARKING SIGN</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';

     while (($row = oci_fetch_array($fabParse, OCI_BOTH)) != false) {
            echo '<tbody>';
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['PROJECT'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['MARKING_FAB_DATE'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['MARKING_FAB_SIGN'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tbod>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
```

and the SQL,

```
Insert into WELTESADMIN.FABRICATION
(HEAD_MARK, ID, CUTTING, ASSEMBLY, WELDING, 
DRILLING, FINISHING, REV_DATE, CUTTING_FAB_DATE, ASSEMBLY_FAB_DATE, 
CUTTING_FAB_SIGN, ASSEMBLY_FAB_SIGN, MARKING, MARKING_FAB_DATE, MARKING_FAB_SIGN)

Values
('SMS-PW-BM104', 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, TO_DATE('05/05/2014 12:34:34', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('05/06/2014 13:48:56',  'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('05/06/2014 13:48:57', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
'kasmuji', 'kasmuji', 1, TO_DATE('05/06/2014 13:48:55', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'kasmuji');
```

So the problem is undefined index in MARKING_FAB_DATE and MARKING_FAB_SIGN. I really dont know whats wrong with this.

thanks

Comment: Two or more tables with name `FABRICATION` ? Did you try _prefixing_ the schema name in your `SELECT` query. Index do not create any problem with Selection.

Comment: Can you post exact error?

Comment: @gafreax here is the error, 

Notice: Undefined index: CUTTING_FAB_DATE in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\testing.php on line 46

Notice: Undefined index: CUTTING_FAB_SIGN in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\testing.php on line 47

Comment: @OracleUser i didnt prefix the schema. Column that dont give error when i retrieved are HEAD_MARK, ID, CUTTING, ASSEMBLY, WELDING, 
DRILLING, FINISHING, REV_DATE. The rest of them gave me errors

Comment: @Chriskonz can you dump $row?

Comment: @gafreax it shows like this,

Notice: Undefined index: CUTTING_FAB_DATE in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\testing.php on line 48
NULL 
Notice: Undefined index: CUTTING_FAB_SIGN in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\testing.php on line 49
NULL

Comment: @Chriskonz yes, but if you do a var_dump($row) before reading fields, what do you see?